# How to use SetSerializationOptions method in official mongo-csharp-driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I used it just like:

```
  DateTimeSerializationOptions op = new DateTimeSerializationOptions(true);
      cursor = mc.Find(queryArg).SetLimit(limit).SetSkip(skip).SetSortOrder(sort).SetSerializationOptions(op);
```

it set dateOnly, but it seems to be no work, have I made mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

`SetSerializationOptions` is normally used to globally define the way a certain type is *serialized*. In your code, you're trying to use it for *deserialization* (reading).

I'm not sure why you can set the serialization options on `MongoCursor`, but as the documentation says: "Only needed in rare cases". I looked up the source, and it seems to be largely ignored by the driver.

You probably want to change the serialization behavior:

### Using an Attribute

the easiest way to serialize only the date component is using an attribute:

```
public class Test
{
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(DateOnly = true)]
    public DateTime SomeDate {get; set;}
}
```

### Using Class Map

Alternatively, you can also register this manually:

```
BsonClassMap<Test> map = new BsonClassMap<Test>();
map.MapProperty(p => p.SomeDate).
          SetSerializationOptions(DateTimeSerializationOptions.DateOnlyInstance);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so what should I do to get date Only,actually,I want to get LocalTime if bsonValue Type is dateTime which stored UTC in server .

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. If you want to have date only, it makes sense to use one of the options above. Changing it on reading is a bit strange, and should be used only when migrating data I think. Alternatively, you could change your model so it contains a publically accessible date-only DateTime field.